# Failed to bring up eth1

Tags: networking

We try to implement the ubuntu server as Gateway. There are two NIC cards . One is for Internet and another is for LAN.
eth0 is up but eth1 is failed to up.
I need to configure eth0 as

```
address 172.16.1.200
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway : 172.16.1.1
DNS server : 172.16.1.1
```

and I need to configure eth1 as

```
address 192.168.21.1
mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.21.1
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 5 interfaces`, which says, in part:

```
NAME  
   /etc/network/interfaces - network interface configuration for ifup and ifdown  

DESCRIPTION  
   /etc/network/interfaces  contains  
network interface configuration information  
for the ifup(8) and ifdown(8) commands.  

This is where you configure how your system is connected to the network.
```

Then, carefully (with manual backup copy), edit the file. Read `man 8 ifup` and `man 8 ifdown`, too.

Comment: But how i edit in the scripts

Comment: I'm sorry, but "We try to implement the ubuntu server as Gateway", and "how I edit in the scripts" tell me that the best advice I can give you is to get local assistance from someone who is computer literate, and familiar with Linux editors, configuration files, system management, etc.